# Getting YouTube video length in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-youtube-api

I'm creating an app which will display YouTube video. I want to get the length of that video. For example: When the user watches YouTube video for 30 seconds they will get 20 points. Is there any way to get the length. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `YouTubePlayer.getDurationMillis()` to obtain the video duration in milliseconds.